What is the relationship between the side lengths of two rectangles, one of which is inscribed within the other?
Suppose rectangle $A$ with side lengths $w$ and $h$ is inscribed within rectangle $B$ with side lengths $W$ and $H$. All vertices of $A$ lie on the sides of $B$ (but not the vertices of $B$). What is the relationship between $w$, $h$, $W$, and $H$?
You can assume that $A$'s side of length $w$ is at an angle less than $\pi/4$ with $B$'s side of length $W$.
I found a similar question, but I believe it uses an incompatible setup: How to find sides of rectangle that is inscribed in other rectangle?

There are infinitely many inscribed rectangles. HINT: the triangles formed at four corners are similar.

@Intelligentipauca I know that, I want to know the relationship between the side lengths of the two rectangles. If you know three, how to calculate the fourth? I believe there is only one or two solutions in that case.

From triangle similarity we have (see figure below):
$$
(H-x):y=(W-y):x,
\quad\text{that is}\quad
(H-x)x=(W-y)y.
$$
Moreover:
$$
w^2=x^2+y^2
\quad\text{and}\quad
h^2=(W-y)^2+(H-x)^2.
$$
To find the relation between $H$, $W$, $h$, $w$ we must eliminate $x$ and $y$ from the three equations above. A tedious task that I handed over to Mathematica. Here's the result:
$$
h^8 - 2 h^6 H^2 + h^4 H^4 - 4 h^6 w^2 + 2 h^4 H^2 w^2 + 
 2 h^2 H^4 w^2 + 6 h^4 w^4 + 2 h^2 H^2 w^4 + H^4 w^4\\ 
- 4 h^2 w^6 -  2 H^2 w^6 + w^8 - 2 h^6 W^2 + 2 h^4 H^2 W^2 + 2 h^4 w^2 W^2 - 
 12 h^2 H^2 w^2 W^2\\ 
+ 2 h^2 w^4 W^2 + 2 H^2 w^4 W^2 - 2 w^6 W^2 + h^4 W^4 + 2 h^2 w^2 W^4 + w^4 W^4=0
$$

EDIT.
The above equation is biquadratic in $W$, hence an explicit solution for $W^2$ can be easily found:
$$
W^2=
\frac{h^6-h^4 (H^2+w^2)+h^2w^2(6 H^2 -w^2)-H^2 w^4+w^6
\pm 4 h H w (w^2-h^2) \sqrt{h^2-H^2+w^2}}
{\left(h^2+w^2\right)^2}
$$
A similar solution can be found for $H^2$. It is much harder to find an explicit solution for $h^2$ or $w^2$, for in that case one must solve a quartic equation.

Most tedious! My solution involved constructing a diagonal of the inner rectangle, calculating the angle of that diagonal to the sides of the outer rectangle using trigonometry, doing some angle arithmetic, and then using trigonometry again to calculate $W$ as a function of $H$, $h$, and $w$. I'll try to post it soon.

@kpjoshi As a matter of fact, my equation can be seen as a quadratic equation for $W^2$, hence one can easily find a formula for $W^2$, or for $H^2$. Not so for $h^2$ of $w^2$: in that case one must solve a quartic equation.
